# "Publisher Could Not Be Verified" on .dll

Tags: windows-10, dll, security-warning

One of my .dll files is unsigned, and every single time I run the program that uses it, it pops up with this warning:

[image: popup]

I've tried to edit the following registry key to include both `.exe` and `.dll` files `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Associations\LowRiskFileTypes`, but it still gives me the warning. How can I get rid of this? I don't mind if I have to disable the warning globally or anything, I'm just sick of seeing it. And to be clear, this file is not on a network share or anything--it's just on my hard drive.

I'm running the latest build (not Insider) of Windows 10 Home by the way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/341091/how-to-get-rid-of-the-publisher-cannot-be-verified-on-network-files and https://superuser.com/questions/853171/windows-security-warning-on-all-files-on-local-drives and https://superuser.com/questions/1256560/we-cant-verify-who-created-this-file/1256574#1256574

Comment: Relevant with regards to the last duplicate https://superuser.com/questions/1018145/windows-starter-edition-home-and-home-premium-do-not-include-gpedit-how-do-i-i

Comment: @Ramhound All group policy editor does is provide a GUI for changing registry values, right? I don't think it would help because I don't have 10 Pro so it just doesn't look for those keys (unless I'm mistaken).

Comment: The duplicates are more than just that single key you modified.

Comment: @Ramhound The answers either refer to accessing files on network shares or using the exact registry key that I mentioned. As I said, the registry key does not work for me, and I am not accessing files over a network, so neither of these apply to me and I still do not have a solution.

Comment: "am not accessing files over a network" - Your question does mention this fact.  Could you provide the relevant information from the Security and General tab on the properties of the file in question?

Comment: Sorry, I thought the lack of mentioning it made it clear it was not happening, especially since there are multiple other questions relating to this issue for files over a network--sadly I would have fixed this by now if that were the issue. I'm not sure what information you need, but everyone has read and execute permission for it, and the owner is SYSTEM.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get rid of "the publisher cannot be verified" on network files?](https://superuser.com/questions/341091/how-to-get-rid-of-the-publisher-cannot-be-verified-on-network-files)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to create a self-signed CA (**C**ertificate **A**uthority), using it to sign a code signing cert, which then signs `BPSRegWD64.dll` *(provided you 100% trust that library)*.

Use `openssl` to create the CA and code signing cert, then [**`SignTool.exe`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/signtool-exe) to sign `BPSRegWD64.dll`

1. **Install [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/community-downloads/), ensuring `C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin` is added to System `PATH`** 
    *OpenSSL doesn't create Windows binaries, so it's simpler to install software it's bundled within*
2. **Download this [`openssl.cnf`](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/OpenSSL/openssl.cnf) to Create Required Certs *([KU and EKU info](https://superuser.com/a/1248085/529800))*:** 
    *Save as `%UserProfile%\Documents\SSL\openssl.cnf`; req. commands/info begin on Line 430*

   1. **Create required directories and files for OpenSSL via a PowerShell terminal:** 
       **<kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>** > *Open:* `Powershell` > OK

      ```powershell
      # Create PowerShell variable for $docs:
        $docs = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyDocuments")

      # Create OpenSSL Directories
        MkDir "$docs\SSL\ca"
        MkDir "$docs\SSL\cert"
        MkDir "$docs\SSL\crl"
        MkDir "$docs\SSL\csr"
        MkDir "$docs\SSL\key"
        MkDir "$docs\SSL\p12"

      # Create File: crlnumber
        Echo 01 > "$docs\SSL\crl\crlnumber"

      # Create File: index
        Echo > "$docs\SSL\index"

      # Create File: rand
        Echo > "$docs\SSL\rand"

      # Create File: serial
        Echo 00 > "$docs\SSL\serial"

      # Enter SSL Directory
        Cd "$docs\SSL"
      ```
   2. **Generate self-signed CA:**

      ```powershell
      OpenSSL req -x509 -new -sha512 -days 3650 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout ".\ca\CA.key.pem" -out ".\ca\CA.crt.pem" -config ".\openssl.cnf" -extensions v3_signing_ica
      ```

      *CA key should have a secure passphrase of **at least** 20 characters, containing at minimum: 
       2 uppercase letters, 2 lowercase letters, 2 numbers, and 2 symbols*
   3. **Generate the CSR (C*ertificate* S*igning* R*equest*) for the Signing Cert:** 
       Modify `openssl.cnf` Line 244 *(`email.1 = user@email.com`)* with user's email, then:

      ```powershell
      OpenSSL req -out ".\csr\Signing.csr" -new -days 3650 -sha512 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout ".\key\Signing.key.pem" -config ".\openssl.cnf" -extensions v3_codesign
      ```

      *Cert key should have a secure passphrase of **at least** 16 characters inline with **#2.2***
   4. **Sign the Signing Cert with the CA:**

      ```powershell
      OpenSSL x509 -req -sha512 -days 3650 -in ".\csr\Signing.csr" -CA ".\ca\CA.crt.pem" -CAkey ".\ca\CA.key.pem" -CAserial .\serial -out ".\cert\Signing.crt.pem" -extfile ".\openssl.cnf" -extensions v3_codesign
      ```
   5. **Export the Signing cert as a PKCS12 cert:**

      ```powershell
      OpenSSL pkcs12 -export -out ".\p12\Signing.p12" -inkey ".\key\Signing.key.pem" -in ".\cert\Signing.crt.pem" -certfile ".\ca\CA.crt.pem"
      ```

      *PKCS12 should have a secure passphrase of **at least** 16 characters inline with **#2.2***
3. **Import Certs into Cert Manager (`certmgr.msc`):**

   1. **Register `.pem` Extension as a Valid Certificate:** 
       Open an Admin Terminal via: **<kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>** > *Open:* `Powershell` > **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>** > OK

      ```powershell
      Reg ADD "HKCR\.pem" /T REG_SZ /d CERfile ; Reg ADD "HKCR\.pem" /V "Content Type" /T REG_SZ /D application/x-x509-ca-cert ; Pause ; Exit
      ```
   2. **Import CA as a *Trusted Root Certificate Authority*:** 
       Right-click `CA.crt.pem` > Install Certificate > Local Machine > Next > Approve UAC > 
       *Place all certificates in the following store* > Browse... > *Trusted Root Certification Authorities* 
       OK > Next > Finish
   3. **Import PKCS12 as a  *Personal Certificate*:** 
       Right-click `Signing.p12` > Install PFX > Current User > Next > *Filename:* 
       `%UserProfile%\Documents\SSL\p12\Signing.p12` > Next > Enter passphrase > Next > OK
4. **Sign `BPSRegWD64.dll` via:**

   1. **[`Set-AuthenticodeSignature`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-authenticodesignature):**

      1. Create `Sign.ps1` script:

         ```powershell
         Cmd /C Echo '#

                 ##::[[---  PowerShell Signing Script  ---]]::##

             # Paramaters #
         #----------------------------------------------------------------

         # Error if no file is specified:
           param([string] $file=$(throw "Please specify a script filepath."))

         # Auto select user signing certificate:
           $Cert = Get-ChildItem -Path "Cert:\CurrentUser\My" -CodeSigningCert

         # SHA256 TimeStamp server:
           $timeStampURL = "http://sha256timestamp.ws.symantec.com/sha256/timestamp"


             # Script #
         #----------------------------------------------------------------
         if($cert) {
             Set-AuthenticodeSignature -filepath $file -Certificate $Cert -HashAlgorithm SHA256 -TimestampServer $timeStampURL
         }
         else {
             throw "Did not find certificate with friendly name of `"$certFriendlyName`""
         }' > "C:\Sign.ps1"
         ```
      2. Execute `Sign.ps1`:

         ```powershell
         C:\Sign.ps1 "C:\Path\to\BPSRegWD64.dll"
         ```
   2. **[`SignTool.exe`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/signtool-exe):**

      1. **Install the [Windows SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive):  *Signing Tools for Desktop Apps*:** 
          Ensure path to `SignTool.exe` is added to the System `PATH`:

         - `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System` > Adv. system settings > 
            Env Variables > System Variables > Path > Edit > New > `signtool.exe` path > 
            OK > OK > OK 
            *Example path: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.18362.0\x64`* 

            *There are certain file extensions PowerShell's `Set-AuthenticodeSignature` can sign that `SignTool` cannot, and vice versa, but I'm unsure which can and cannot sign what files, so it's best to also install the SDK's `SignTool`.*
      2. Execute `SignTool.exe`:

         ```powershell
         SignTool Sign /S My /FD SHA256 /TD SHA256 /TR "http://sha256timestamp.ws.symantec.com/sha256/timestamp" "C:\Path\to\BPSRegWD64.dll"
         ```

Comment: Attempting step 2 gives me: Error Loading extension section v3_codesign
1204:error:0D06407A:asn1 encoding routines:a2d_ASN1_OBJECT:first num too large:crypto/asn1/a_object.c:72:
1204:error:2206706E:X509 V3 routines:v2i_EXTENDED_KEY_USAGE:invalid object identifier:crypto/x509v3/v3_extku.c:93:section:,name:mcCTLSign,value:
1204:error:22098080:X509 V3 routines:X509V3_EXT_nconf:error in extension:crypto/x509v3/v3_conf.c:47:name=extendedKeyUsage, value=codeSigning, msCodeInd, msCodeCom, mcCTLSign, timeStamping

Comment: @Kurausukun The issue was a typo in the `openssl.cnf` at line 414, char 70 with EKU `msCTLSign` _(had a typo listing it as `mcCTLSign`)_. Once corrected, the CSR is created without error. _(I will update the `openssl.cnf` on my GitHub tomorrow, but I want to double-check others before committing the typo correction. Please either manually edit line 414 or do a find and replace for `mcCTLSig` to `msCTLSign`.)_ **I also corrected some file/directory naming inconsistencies in the commands, so before re-issuing, please ensure your CA's cert and key are moved into `%UserProfile%\Documents\SSL\ca`**

Comment: @Kurausukun I realized I left out `SignTool`'s command and have updated the answer with it.  There are two ways to sign files, either via PowerShell's `Set-AuthenticodeSignature` or `SignTool.exe`, however there are certain files one can sign that the other cannot and vice versa; I'm unsure which can do `.dll` files, so I've included both.